# Android Studio / gradle: "Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'"

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have two modules in Android Studio.

Main is the application and Sub is a library module. Sub is referred from Main with `compile project(':Sub')` in the gradle script. That works when run from Android Studio. But when run from command line, gradlew says:

```
Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/ResolvedComponentResult
```

This is the important parts in Main's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile project (':Sub')
}
```

The Sub gradle file is more or less identical, but has

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'
```

instead of 'android'

I have tried with gradle 1.9 and 1.10, but same result.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: This tends to happen because of a mismatch between the version of Gradle and the version of the Android Gradle plugin. If you're using 0.9 of the plugin, you should be using 1.10 or 1.11 of Gradle. Are you using the wrapper when you build from the command line? You have multiple modules; does one of the modules perhaps specify a different version of the plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Verify that your dependencies contains `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'` in each `gradle.build` file (or just put it in the base one and not declare it in the others).  Update `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to point to gradle 1.11:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

If you have any other instances of the gradle-wrapper (such as if you originally made the library project on its own and later added an example app), verify that all instances are updated to point to the same version (each `gradle-wrapper.properties` file).